# Slow query with VIEW and LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to get a 30 day view of transaction totals as a graph. Currently using a VIEW for dates and LEFT OUTER JOIN to get data. This works, showing my SUM of all my transactions, and still including a 0 for days without transactions, etc.

The problem is that the transactions table is quite large. So that LEFT OUTER JOIN is doing a lot of work... and is slow. Here is the original query:

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(Total), 0) AS OrderTotal, MONTH(dates.date) AS Month, YEAR(dates.date) AS Year, DAY(dates.date) AS Day
FROM dates LEFT OUTER JOIN tblTransactions
ON DATE(tblTransactions.TransDate) = dates.date
WHERE dates.date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
GROUP BY DAY(dates.date), MONTH(dates.date)
ORDER BY dates.date
LIMIT 30
```

To speed things up, I thought it would be good to add an additional WHERE condition and only look at transactions older than 30 days. That sped things up incredibly, and thought I dialed it, but the problem is that it's only good if I have transactions for all 30 days. If one day is $0, it would return 29 records with this conditional. Not good.

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(Total), 0) AS OrderTotal, MONTH(dates.date) AS Month, YEAR(dates.date) AS Year, DAY(dates.date) AS Day
FROM dates LEFT OUTER JOIN tblTransactions
ON DATE(tblTransactions.TransDate) = dates.date
WHERE dates.date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
AND tblTransactions.TransDate > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
GROUP BY DAY(dates.date), MONTH(dates.date)
ORDER BY dates.date
LIMIT 30
```

So was hoping for some feedback to improve the original query. Right now, I have a feeling a PHP for() loop - looping 30 times and querying 30 times might be faster than my original LEFT OUTER JOIN single query.

Comment: In addition to trying the answer of Gordon Linoff,

Try setting the value of DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) to a variable and use it in query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filtering on the second table in a `left join` needs to go in the `on` clause:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(t.Total), 0) AS OrderTotal,
       MONTH(d.date) AS Month, YEAR(dates.date) AS Year, DAY(d.date) AS Day
FROM dates d LEFT OUTER JOIN
     tblTransactions t
     ON DATE(t.TransDate) = d.date AND
        t.TransDate > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
WHERE d.date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
GROUP BY DAY(d.date), MONTH(d.date)
ORDER BY d.date
LIMIT 30;
```

Note:  A cause for bad performance is likely this clause:

```
DATE(t.TransDate) = d.date
```

If `TransDate` has no time component then this is not necessary.  If performance on this type of query is important, add a computed column for just the date component of `TransDate` and add an index on that column.

Comment: Thank you. Works great. I also created a new field with just date and indexed that. Speed is snappy.